# Trivial $\pi$ action for $H$-space

Tags: algebraic-topology

The action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_n$ can be given by the the map $S^n\rightarrow S^n\vee I$ which collpses the northern hemisphere via latitudes and then assigning $\gamma(f)=f\vee\gamma$ for $\gamma\in\pi_1$ and $f\in \pi_n$.

There is a claim by Hatcher (and it seems this is a standard result). That a $H$-space has the above action is trivial. I cannot seem to find a proof of this. I've seen somewhere that we can show a homotopy between this action and the product action $f\gamma(x)=f(x)\gamma(|x|)$ and from this define a homotopy to $f$ and thus show action is trivial. However i was wondeirng wether anyone new the details, for exmaple how the first homotopy is constructed.